# Spring Cloud Data Flow - declare dependency on another job

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

I want to create job (a composed task, specifically), that declares a dependency on starting based on whether a previous job completed.

I've not seen how one could do this with SCDF. Is this possible?